# Which java open-source portal platform to choose these days?

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet, portal

Our company is developing a portal and portlet based enterprise application.

Could you recommend which open-source portal platform is good for developers and can be integrated with Oracle WebLogic server. Oracle WebCenter Portal is not an option to us.

I've read some information about Liferay, eXo-platform, GateIn, but I want some experienced developer opinions, which is better and why.

Can you describe any pros and cons of platform you are using?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In our organisation we are currently using Liferay 6.0.6, the community edition. Our experience developing our extranet portal has been as expected.
You can extend (some) functionalities in runtime like themes, portlets, hooks. I've found nothing I can't do with Liferay during our development and deploy and we've used many different features of portlets (asynch, friendly urls, interportlet comm, service builder, etc.), built a theme, extended the i18n and the registration, etc.

Now you can use the 6.1.0 version or even the 6.2.0 (currently in development) which supports more fancy functionalities to ease web development and a necessary model reorganization affecting organizations, sites and so on.

The community is very very active and also has the enterprise version with support, bugfixes, service packs, ...

I'm not a Liferay expert, I've just been using it for half a year, but I like it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Liferay is better than any of it open source counter parts when it comes to community support.

Comment: [check this out](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6764179)

Comment: You can adapt LifeRay portal enterprise for just about any type of business purpose. The enterprise edition comes with some additional performance, monitoring, soa and other social media features.
It is growing and there are very active groups in Australia.